# Antipodal points of sphere

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Whenever $S^2$ is the union of three closed subsets $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$, then at least one of these sets must contain a pair of antipodal points {${x,-x}$} in $S^{2}$

This is homework from topology (undergraduate)

Can you help me ?

Comment: Disjoint union, or any kind of union?

Comment: Check out this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem and the  Lusternik–Schnirelmann theorem.

Comment: igor Rivin / any kind of union

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct a function $f \colon S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by setting $f(x) = (d(x,A_1), d(x,A_2))$ where $d$ is the standard metric on $S^2$. Apply the Borsuk-Ulam theorem to this function.

Details of the general case (the Lusternik–Schnirelmann theorem) can be found in Armstrong's book.

Comment: you mean that there exists antipodal points {x,-x} s.t. f(x)=f(-x). This means that d(-x,A_1)=d(x,A_1), d(-x,A_2)=d(x,A_2) for some x. so you mean A_3 has antipodal points if A_1, A_2 have no antipodal points?

Comment: That's the idea, yes!

Comment: thx a lot for ur help